# A list of Shapes and their escaped codes

Tags: html, ascii, shapes

I need a list of HTML escaped codes that represents shapes. I want the codes to be compatible with all browsers. For example, I want an escaped code to show a square on the page, in another page I want a triangle. From what I've heard it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about *characters* that look like basic geometrical shapes, try opening *charmap* on Windows or a similar if you're on a different OS.  As long as your HTML is using a Unicode encoding (like UTF-8), you can simply use those characters directly in your source code.  If your code is written in something like ASCII, then you can use the numeric value of the character with a numeric *entity*, like this: `&#x25b2;` (will render a ▲).  Keep in mind that the character will only render if the font you're using to display it contains the character.